# Blazor NavigationManager.NavigateTo() Does not work correctly

Tags: c#, navigation, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor project. I want to redirect to another page from the index. but it doesnt work. It does set the email in the url. but not the page. this to be exacted: http://localhost:5007/?email=1%401.nl#. But i expect it to be: http://localhost:5007/CreateOrder/email=1%401.nl#

here is the code:

the function where i call the navigateTo in the index

```
    public async void checkEmailUniqueness()
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        orderManager = new OrderManager(httpClient);

        //receives the result of the mail uniqueness, True or False
        bool result = await orderManager.CheckEmailUniqueness(mail);
        
        //ToDO fix de routing errors / dat ie niet wil navigeren
        if (result)
        {
            //ToDo create and navigate to edit order
        }
        else
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/CreateOrder/" + mail);
        }
    }
```

and the createOrder

```
@page "/CreateOrder/{Mail}"
@using BroodnodigFrontend.Managers
<PageTitle>Create Order</PageTitle>

//some html stuff i wont show because it just takes up space//

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    


}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the first slash `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("CreateOrder/...`

Comment: that does not work, it still does the same thing

Comment: Is the value of `mail` `email=1%401.nl#`? If so, I just wrote a quick little test and it's working as you are expecting it to. I get `http://localhost:5007/CreateOrder/email=1%401.nl#` and if I emit the value of `Mail` to the page it shows as `email=1@1.nl`.

Comment: i dont get /Createorder, i only get email=(email here), thats the whole issue

http://localhost:5007/?email=1%401.nl